# MSBuild Post Build task to execute an EXE

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

**I wish to execute an EXE as a part of my post MSBuild tasks** , once all the projects in my solution are build (The exe should get executed only after the complete build of my solution and not the individual projects).

Now how do i accomplish that ? I guess  i need to add a post build task item in the MSBuild.

Can someone suggest a solution with an example ?

Answer (score 1):

Not certain if you have MSBuild project file for generating the build. If yes then this is a straight forward by creating a target that depends on all other projects that you need to build. For example,

```
<Target Name="PostBuildProcessing" DependsOnTargets="<List of targets that are generating build>">
    <Exec Command="<give your command here>" />
</Target>
```

DependsOnTarget should be the target(s) that is building the solution (or projects).